# Android: 2 or more ExpandableListView inside Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

How could I do something like this?

[image]

Two expandable listview inside navigation drawer. I tryed to add it inside my xml but without luck.
What I want is a view with only one scrollbar, but I don't' know how to do it..

this is my navigation drawer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/Bianco"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/tvHomeActions"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/elvHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/tvHomeNavigations"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/elvNavigateTo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:**
I wanna create something like drawer in Gmail app

Comment: I think the 3 is a counter, not the item count inside the item, for your quesiton I also think there is no 2 different Expandable ListViews. Think Title 1 and Title 2 as dividers, i don't have to code how to add them though.

Comment: Ok, but if you look the screenshots posted by LOG_TAG "item 3" has a "3" and it is closed.  I think that if "Item 3" could be opened it would be like "Item 4" that has 3 child. 
Anyway now I removed all and I added only one explandable listview. 
I think that the key of all is in groups or headerviews inside the expandable listview..
Ps. sorry all for my english ;)

Comment: No, the 3 inside the box indicates that there are three items to be viewed in the fragment evoked by pressing that button (like 4 unread messages when pressing inbox)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

Finally i have got it! 
This is the code I created to get an ExpandableListView with section titles.
Now it's I can easily create three xml custom layouts for titles, groups and childrens.

It work for me, but I accept any code improvements to optimize memory usage, speed and so on.

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// NAVIGATION DRAWER SIDE FRAGMENT
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private ExpandableListView mDrawerListView;
private List<Elemento> mainActions = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<Integer, List<String>> childActions = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    assert v != null;

    mDrawerListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.elvHome);
    mDrawerListView.setGroupIndicator(null);

    // add first title
    mainActions.add(new TitoloGruppo("Good guys"));                     // 0
    mainActions.add(new Azione("Admiral Ackbar", "Dagobah System"));    // 1
    mainActions.add(new Azione("Han Solo", "Millenium Falcon"));        // 2
    mainActions.add(new Azione("Yoda", "Dagobah System"));              // 3
    // add second title
    mainActions.add(new TitoloGruppo("Bad guys"));                      // 4
    mainActions.add(new Azione("Emperor", "Death star 2"));             // 5
    mainActions.add(new Azione("Jabba", "Tatooine"));                   // 6
    mainActions.add(new Azione("Grand Moff Tarkin", "Death star 1"));   // 7

    // Adding child quotes to Ackbar
    List<String> mainSubFive = new ArrayList<>();
    mainSubFive.add("It's a trap!");

    // Adding child quotes to Yoda
    List<String> mainSubThree = new ArrayList<>();
    mainSubThree.add("Do or do not; there is no try.");
    mainSubThree.add("There is … another … Sky … walker.…");
    mainSubThree.add("When 900 years old you reach, look as good you will not ehh.");

    childActions.put(0, new ArrayList<String>());
    childActions.put(1, mainSubFive);
    childActions.put(2, new ArrayList<String>());
    childActions.put(3, mainSubThree);
    childActions.put(4, new ArrayList<String>());
    childActions.put(5, new ArrayList<String>());
    childActions.put(6, new ArrayList<String>());

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), mainActions, childActions));
    mDrawerListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            List<String> list = childActions.get(groupPosition);
            if(list.size() > 0)
                return false;
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ ((Azione) mainActions.get(groupPosition)).getSubtitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    mDrawerListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            List<String> list = childActions.get(groupPosition);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + list.get(childPosition).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return v;
}


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// INTERNAL CLASS
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

protected class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Elemento> mainElements;
    private HashMap<Integer, List<String>> childElements;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<Elemento> mainElements, HashMap<Integer, List<String>> childElements) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mainElements = mainElements;
        this.childElements = childElements;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.mainElements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if(this.childElements.get(groupPosition) == null)
            return 0;
        return this.childElements.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.mainElements.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.childElements.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Elemento i = mainElements.get(groupPosition);
        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isGroupSection()){
                final TitoloGruppo si = (TitoloGruppo)i;
                v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);
                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                sectionView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC800"));
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            }else if(i.isAction()){
                Azione ei = (Azione)i;
                v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                if (title != null)
                    title.setText(ei.title);
                if(subtitle != null)
                    subtitle.setText("count: " + getChildrenCount(groupPosition));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}   

    public class TitoloGruppo implements Elemento {

    private final String titolo;

    public TitoloGruppo(String titolo) {
        this.titolo = titolo;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return titolo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGroupSection() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAction() {
        return false;
    }
}

protected interface Elemento {
    public boolean isGroupSection();
    public boolean isAction();
}

protected class Azione implements Elemento {
    public final String title;
    public final String subtitle;

    public Azione(String title, String subtitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return this.subtitle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGroupSection() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAction() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Ps. thank you all

Comment: Can you share full source for this or Is it inside activity ?

Comment: Hi, the activity code, is the default Android studio blank project's code

Answer (score 8):

**FYI** the screen shot you have shown in your qsn also have Pinnned or sectioned listview.

**ExpandableListView in navigation drawer:**

[image]

Use this code [DrawerLayoutTest](https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest/tree/HEAD/DrawerLayoutTest) for ExpandableListView in navigation drawer.

**Update**: Here is exactly what you looking for, give it at try for this [michenux  navigation-drawer](http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html) , [Git](https://github.com/Michenux/YourAppIdea)

**Logic:**

1>use ExpandableListView + michenux navigation-drawer  drawer for design and Expandable list view and for that  *count of "3" items inside* use  jgilfelt's android-viewbadger lib.

2>You have to play around in getview(..) in the listview for disabling enabling the drop down icon of the expandable listview, it the item has no child (check for array or arraylist is null/empty) and make visible invisible the badger (drop down count icon/badger) thats it or simply change the list view item layout depending on the each item values Ex: for list row contains expandable childs load different layout with view badger !

Credits: Michenaud,Jgilfelt

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't think that my screenshot is related to a pinned listview.
I think that it is an expanded listview ("TopView 4" as a count of "3" items inside) on top and a listview at bottom. And that is what I want.
I checked out your link but that is not what i am looking for.. 
Thank you again ;)

Comment: I wanna create something like drawer in Gmail app

Comment: @crc_error you have to play around in get view for disabling enabling the drop down icon of the expandable listview, it the item has no child (check for array or arraylist is null/empty) and make visible invisible the badger (drop down count icon/badger) thats it  !