# How to add other layout within NavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, navigationview

I'm trying to add  Expandlistview within my NavigationView but it fails.
Can I add layout below header?

[image]

*activity_main layout*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">  

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: lemme see your whole activity or on the part where you set the drawer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112832/android-2-or-more-expandablelistview-inside-navigation-drawer

Comment: @Sree I wanna add header like metrial design

Comment: When you are nesting any view inside `NavigationView` then **app:menu** and **app:headerLayout** **will not work** properly.. you have to inflate your headerview progrmatically and add it to `ExpandableListView` using `addHeaderView()`

Comment: You can have one solution for this is, **apply fixed width to your root element of your header layout and give the same size `marginTop` to your `ExpandableListView`.**

Comment: thank you for help . I think so too. @Moinkhan

Comment: Don't use the NavigationView to obtain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be .. if you are using header layout with specific height, for ex 200dp.. then in activity_main.xml include margin top 0f 210dp for expandable listview tag.. I hope you are not using menu for navigation view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">  

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use listview in navigation drawer list and append header view to the list which contains expandable listview. I am not sure but you can check it