# How to add a sub list under a item in android navigation drawer fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I am new to android. I am working with fragment. I have taken the default navigation drawer fragment activity while create a project in android studio. There is 3 item in the drawer by default. Well now I want a sub list under any one of the 3 item. I have watched a number of tutorial but could not make it work with the default settings. Can any one please help me on this please ?!!! I have not done anything for the easy way of doing it just take the project. So that I am not providing any code cause it's default code. Please help if possible.

Comment: Here are some useful links.  http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-custom-navigation-drawer-with.html

Comment: Check This---> https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112832/android-2-or-more-expandablelistview-inside-navigation-drawer

Comment: i am not clear what you want may be you looking for navigationview https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html  which can implemented using normal menu items where you can declare groups and items

Comment: thank u all. @Pavan, bro I mean to say that we can have fragment and list item in navigation drawer fragment activity when we create project. so can't we just add some sub list item under any one of it .